# nrwl/nx How to publish a NestJs library with npm?

Tags: typescript, npm, nestjs, nrwl, nrwl-nx

I need some help, by creating a publishable nestjs library with nx.
I've read a lot of documentations, but nothing helps.

I wrote a nestjs library in a NX monorepository. Now i want to publish only this library on NPM, but i dont know how.

On official NX documentation i found a flag named "--publishable". The only problem is you can't use it together with a NestJs library. If you enter a command like this:

```
ng g @nrwl/nest:library mylib --publishable
```

you will get an error:

```
Unknown Option: "--publishable".
```

So with a NestJs library this flag doesnt work.

Now i want to create a package.json on my own and this is the point i dont know how. I have to build this library and then i have to publish it on npm. 
This process is killing me...

Im using the latest version of NX!

I will be very happy about a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. ng g lib your_lib --publishable
2. ng build your_lib
3. change the contents of  your_lib_.module to reflect that of a
   nestJs.module
4. npm login
5. npm publish inside the dir of your_lib_name

   I hope this helps